# .change on multiple sets of radio buttons to change .html()

Tags: html, jquery

Following are the variants of a product. I am looking to get syntax for .change() so when values are selected it changes pricing based on following calculation:

- Bundle One + Marble Color = 15$
- Bundle One +  Black Color = 18$
- Bundle Two [Most Popular] + Marble color = 25$
- Bundle Two [Most Popular] + Black color = 28$
- Three [Best Offer] + Marble color = 34$
- Three [Best Offer] + Black color = 40$

```
<div>
<label>Choose Bundle</label>
<input class="options-selection__option-value-input" type="radio" name="Bundle+%26+Save" value="One">
<input class="options-selection__option-value-input" type="radio" name="Bundle+%26+Save" value="Two [Most Popular]">
<input class="options-selection__option-value-input" type="radio" name="Bundle+%26+Save" value="Three [Best Offer]">
</div>


<div>
<label>Choose Color</label>
<input class="options-selection__option-value-input" type="radio" name="Choose+Your+Color" value="Marble">
<input class="options-selection__option-value-input" type="radio" name="Choose+Your+Color" value="Black">
</div>

<span class="money">15$</span>
```

I am able to change  value based on 1 set:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[type='radio'][value='Marble']").change(function(){
    $('.money').html("15$");
  });
});
```

But I am confused how to do with 2 sets of radio buttons

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by applying following jQuery Code

```
function chpriceone() {
  if ($("input[type='radio'][value='One']").is(":checked") && $("input[type='radio'][value='Marble']").is(":checked")) {
    $('.money').html("15$");
}}


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[value='One'], input[value='Marble']").click(function() {
    chpriceone();
  });
```